# Type of property value in generic object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to type the `value` parameter of the `setObject` function :

```
type setValueType<T> = (newValue: T) => void

const useObject = () => {
    const setObject = <T>(property: string, value: any, object: T, setValue: setValueType<T>) => {
        setValue({
            ...object,
            [property]: value
        })
    }

    return {
        setObject
    }
}

export default useObject
```

But I don't know what to put for the `value` type.
I want that `value` to be type of `T[property]` but I don't know how to make this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add more generics:

```js
type setValueType<T> = (newValue: T) => void

const useObject = () => {
  const setObject = <
    Obj,
    Prop extends keyof Obj,
    Value extends Obj[Prop]
  >(property: Prop, value: Value, object: Obj, setValue: setValueType<Obj & Record<Prop, Value>>) => {
    setValue({
      ...object,
      [property]: value
    })
  }

  return {
    setObject
  }
}

export default useObject
```

`Prop` generic represents object key/prop

`Obj` generic represents object

`Value` generic represents new value

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: thank you very much, it works like a charm. But it's normal that we don't have to provide a value for the `Prop` generic and the `Value` generic ?

Comment: @AdriHM `Prop` and `Value` generics serves as constraints for our function. Once you provide `object` argument, TS will infer all other generics